# Social Sign on with spring security not establishing connection to Provider API

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-social

I am trying to implement social sign on using spring security and Oauth 2 authentication.The Auth dance between  provider(Linkedin) and my application is not happening. Due to this  my connection object is   returning empty connections.
Please find  more details

JDK version- JDK 1.6_37
   Spring version- spring 3.2.3.RELEASE
   Spring Security Version-3.2.3.RELEASE

pom.xml dependancies

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.brickred</groupId>
        <artifactId>socialauth-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring FB social media connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-instagram</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have a connect controller.When i click on linkedin Link in front end  i am directly redirecting to connect control .Not establishing any connection to Provider.

```
@Autowired
    public IepSocialConnectCtr(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void initController() {
        super.setSessionStrategy(sessionStrategy);
        super.setApplicationUrl(environment.getProperty("site.url"));
    }
    @Override
    public String connectionStatus(@PathVariable
                                   String providerId, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, Model model) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) nativeWebRequest.getNativeResponse();
        String lang = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage();
        setNoCache(nativeWebRequest);
        processFlash(nativeWebRequest, model);
        Map<String, List<Connection<?>>> connections = connectionRepository.findAllConnections();
        if (connections.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Connection is empty");
            return "redirect:/"+ lang+"/";
        }
        return  "redirect:/"+ lang+"/";
    }
```

I have a property file  with client id and secret code which create connection factory for Linkedin and assign it to ConnectionFactoryLocator Object

In the  above code snippet,`connectionRepository.findAllConnections()` is returning empty connections.

Can someone explain me  how application is communicating with provider(connection flow in details ) in Spring social to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

by using your client-secret only your application communicates with provider.the reason for your application is not communicating with provider is,may be you have not configured your id and secret properly.i don't know about linkedin but when connecting with facebook we have to make our application live which was most important thing and many more stuffs to do.
i suggest that you should configure your keys properly.